# Blimp challenge. Doubts about volume at different heights

Tags: gravity, fluid-dynamics, forces

I want to design and build a small semi-rigid airship/dirigible. It will be controlled with RC so I will install motors, arduino, battery etc. Filled with helium.

Weight of the equipment is about 2kg and weight of the dirigible itself (envelope, light internal scaffold...) is unknown since I don't know how big it has to be.

Now, I was all happy calculating the lift force minus weight equals 0, so it stays still:

```
volume * airDensity - volume * heliumDensity + weigh = 0
```

Since I want it to stay still at 3000m, I used 0.91kg/m3 for airDensity (source: Wikipedia) and 0.1256 kg/m3 for heliumDensity (source: WolframAlpha).

**First questions:** are those density values good? Should I count in air temperature? If so, where do I find that data? I want to make the airship fly over some small mountains but the climate there is very cold so I guess air temperature is going to change a lot throughout its flight.

**More questions:** what volume should the airship be design to hold? I don't want it to explode or be dangerously overinflated, so I'm guessing I should design to hold the volume helium will have at 3000m, but what volume is that? Is it affected by airDensity at 3000m since it's surrounding the airship?

I asked a physicist friend of mine but honestly it only confused me more with weird formulas and doubts (as you can see, I'm not a physicist, I wish to be one day though)

If you can't answer **all** questions, any information, examples or whatever that may help me is very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/design/scripts/atmosphere/) website is good for calculating various atmospheric properties based on the [standard atmosphere](http://modelweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/atmos/us_standard.html). In reality, there are large differences day-to-day and especially over unique terrain such as mountains. You will probably need some way to control your altitude such as dropping weights to ascend or venting helium to descend. You should probably design the airship so that you have neutral buoyancy at your max altitude.

Comment: Thanks, that website is pretty useful to get data and I didn't know about it. I still have almost the same doubts though.

Comment: Relating the "put on hold" thing, I don't see how engineers are going to explain what air densities i need to count in and how air temperature and pressure is going to affect how much volum helium is going to take. Anyhow, is there a stackexchange you could recommend for my particular case?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the helium is not in a pressurized container (the balloon is loose, not tightly stretched), nor is it insulated.

So, take an empty balloon, and add $4$ grams of helium.  If you happen to be at Standard Temperature and Pressure (STP), the helium will occupy $22.414$ liters.  It will displace that much air (also at STP).  Since air is a slightly variable mixture of gases, the mass of this volume of air varies slightly, but taking $80 \% $of $28.0$ for the nitrogen, and $20 \% $ of 32.0 for the oxygen, we get a pretty good value of $28.8$ grams.  So the helium would have $24.8$ grams of excess buoyancy at STP.

The important point is that, as the temperature and pressure change, the volume of the helium will change, as will the density of the air being displaced.  But as long as the helium stays unpressurized, and stays in thermal equilibrium with the surrounding air, the $4$ grams of helium will ***always*** have $24.8$ grams of excess buoyancy.

Comment: So what's the volume I should aim for if i want it to be stable at 3000m with a total weight of about 3kg?

Comment: Well, to lift $3,000$ grams (balloon plus actual payload, you'd need around 480 grams of helium, and at STP that would fill a 2.6 cubic meter balloon.  Higher temperatures and lower pressures would increase the volume slightly. "Stable" altitude is irrelevant...

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I don't understand though why altitude is irrelevant? Maybe since both helium and air are less dense in higher altitude they cancel each other out but I can't help but picturing helium "wanting" to occupy more space and therefore improving the chances of my balloon bursting in the air. Where am I wrong?

Comment: A given mass of helium will lift the same mass, independent of altitude; the air and helium do expand in step.  But, yes, the balloon volume gets bigger with altitude.  Some weather balloons are launched and climb steadily until the balloon gets full, taut, and then bursts, letting the parachute take over...

Comment: I thought there was some kind of "altitude barrier" that helium balloons can't get past because they stop lifting because air is too thin?